# How to catch ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a custom error message that tells my coworker what to do when `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError` shown. Yes, i know, it should be as simple as "just run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`!" But i just want to customize the error page, so our development environment could be cooler than ever.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses the web-console gem https://github.com/rails/web-console for this. You can actually style these pages and make changes to the templates if you like, https://github.com/rails/web-console#configweb_consoletemplate_paths

Thats the most generic way to get "awesome" error pages for your developers and more ideal that catching the error yourself, instead of what you are thinking.

Which I think is happening at the framework level

`` actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call' ``

This is the line in the framework trace which is called before the error is raised, I doubt you can rescue it in a controller and do what you need to in a simple way.

Hope this helps.